# How to create square avatar with rounded corners on flutter?

Tags: flutter, widget, avatar

I want to create a widget similar to CircleAvatar, but not rounded.
This is CircleAvatar:

[image: CircleAvatar]

And this is the avatar I want to create:

[image: Square]

I want to know if there is a default widget to do this, as CircleAvatar for rounded avatars.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are so many ways to achieve it but I will only make use one.
Wrap a **ClipRRect()** widget around a **child** widget(this could be an image or any other relevant widget like a Container used in my example). Then, pass `BorderRadius.circular(20.0)`  value to `borderRadius`property of ClipRRect(). That is the active lines of code that create the effect.
Check below for my example:

```dart
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),//or 15.0
  child: Container(
    height: 70.0,
    width: 70.0,
    color: Color(0xffFF0E58),
    child: Icon(Icons.volume_up, color: Colors.white, size: 50.0),
  ),
),
```

[see result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MSKe.jpg)

Comment: While this may be "self-explanatory" to you, adding some explanation could help the OP & future users more and would increase the quality of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ClipRRect` with specified `BorderRadius` property like this:

[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYgd9.jpg)

```
 ClipRRect(
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),//add border radius here
   child: Image.asset('assets/01.jpg'),//add image location here
 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of ClipRRect and Container Widget to achieve the same, use the above code given.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),//or 15.0
  child: Container(
    height: 70.0,
    width: 70.0,
    color: const Color(0xffFF0E58),
    child: const Icon(Icons.volume_up, color: Colors.white, size: 50.0),
  ),
);
  }
}
```