# How to constrain width of ClipRRect image?

Tags: flutter

There are several posts, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63100602/how-to-create-square-avatar-with-rounded-corners-on-flutter), describing how to add rounded corners to an images using ClipRRect. They're working for me except my images aren't constraining properly in width. E.g., my attempt at a square image below

```
ListView(                       // <- Works fine when not in ListView?
 children: <Widget>[
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => _getFromGallery(),
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0), //or 15.0
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: image,
          height: 150.0,
          width: 150.0,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
]
```

has the proper height but the width expands the whole device screen, like this?

[image]

EDIT

This attempt

```
return Container(
    height: 150.0,
    width: 150.0,
    color: Colors.blue,
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0), //or 15.0
      child: CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: image,
        height: 150.0,
        width: 150.0,
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Created this

[image: Edit]

EDIT #2

Image with no ListView

[image]

Comment: can you try BoxFit.fill please?

Comment: apply height and width to container itself should also work

Comment: @tanharpatel, I added your suggestions above but unfortunately still no joy

Comment: @SahdeepSingh unfortunately still no joy

Comment: What is the parent of the Container widget?

Comment: @AnisAlibegić A GestureDetector. I update my OP to show it. The Padding widget is in a ListView

Comment: @buttonsrtoys try `BoxFit.contain` For me its working fine.

Comment: I went further up the tree and ListView seems to be buggering things up. (I updated my original post to show my ListView). Renders fine when removed? I'll add the pic showing no ListView

Answer (score 2):

From the description of ListView, "In the cross axis, the children are required to fill the ListView." So, ListView was expanding my container? Either way, wrapping Padding in a Center widget fixed it.